# Custom Field Order by Last Name and First Name

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I'm looking to find a way to order my query by Last Name first then First Name. I was able to do Last Name although not much luck in the Last Name + First Name part. This is what I came up:

```
$posts = get_posts(
    [
        'post_type'      => 'soldier',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_key'       => 'last_name',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
                'key'     => 'last_name',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order'   => ASC
            ],
            [
                'key'     => 'first_name',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order'   => ASC
            ],
        ],
        'paged'          => $soldier_paged
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues, some unrelated, but generally, you need named meta queries to order by multiple meta keys:

```
$posts = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'soldier',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'          => $soldier_paged,
    'meta_query'     => [
        'last_name_clause'  => [
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ],
        'first_name_clause' => [
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ],
    ],

    'orderby' => [
        'last_name_clause'  => 'ASC',
        'first_name_clause' => 'ASC',
    ],
] );
```

Comment: Hi, it works great! Thanks! Although don't know what you meant by some few issues?

Comment: just `order` and `orderby` were in the wrong place inside `meta_query`- not breaking anything, just not doing anything. also, for arguments like `post_status`, I leave it out if it's the default value.